# Laravel Mix and NPM jQuery is Autoloaded But Is Undefined

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-mix

so I have done the following which seems to solve a lot of issues that trip people up with jQuery and Laravel Mix (4.0):

```
.autoload({
    'jquery': ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
    'clipboard': ['ClipboardJS'],
    'popper.js':  ['Popper']
});
```

This made me stop getting the `$ is not defined` errors.

But now if I console log `$` or `jQuery` or `window.jQuery` it is no longer `is not defined` but `undefined`.

[image: Undefined jQuery]

How can I fix this? The variables are correctly attached to the window but they are empty...

I think I am loading my modules wrong or have some confusion about how the `package.json` and `webpack.mix.js` interact. Full files for each are below:

**package.json:**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
        "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
        "inputmask": "^4.0.6",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "jquery-editable-select": "^2.2.5",
        "jquery-lazy": "^1.7.10",
        "laravel-mix": "4.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
    }
}
```

**webpack.mix.js:**

```
    mix
  .js([



    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Modules
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js',
    'node_modules/jquery-lazy/jquery.lazy.min.js',
    'node_modules/jquery-lazy/jquery.lazy.plugins.js',
    'resources/modules/jRange/jquery.range-min.js',
    'node_modules/inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js',
    'node_modules/clipboard/dist/clipboard.min.js',
    'resources/js/app.js'
  ], 'public/js/app.js')
  .autoload({
    'jquery': ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
    'clipboard': ['ClipboardJS'],
    'popper.js': ['Popper']
  });
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. I tried on `npm run dev` and `npm run production` and get the same error `undefined` output.

Comment: Just to make sure, what does your bootstrap.js look like? And what version of Laravel and Webpack?

Answer (score 1):

So, using mix out of the box to get jQuery, I do:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .version();
```

Then in resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js:

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Webpack does everything else.

And, yes, npm is installing jQuery, as here is my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "vue": "^2.5.16"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.5",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts": "^1.0.9",
        "ar.js": "^1.4.10",
        "chess.js": "^0.10.2",
        "chessboardjs": "0.0.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.4.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
        "typeface-raleway": "0.0.54"
    }
}
```

Comment: I only had to `import "bootstrap"` before binding jquery to the window object in `bootstrap.js` file and it worked.